# Perfect Hash Family Non-Distinct t Columns Calculator

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

Perfect Hash Families (PHFs) are a widely studied combinatorial object. Essentially, they are 4-tuples `(N; t, k, v)`, where the PHF is an `N` by `k` array of `v` symbols. For any `t` columns chosen, there is at least one row of those chosen columns that has no symbol duplicated in that row.

I want to be able to count how many "non-distinct" `t`-column choices there are in a given PHF. My code is below, with some sample inputs that I made up:

```
from itertools import combinations

def get_column(phf, c):
    return [x[c] for x in phf]

# returns the PHF as if we restrict to the "cs" columns (a list)
def combine_columns_into_array(phf, cs):
    r = []
    for c in cs:
        r.append(get_column(phf, c))
    return list(map(list, zip(*r)))

# returns the number of t-column choices that have no distinct rows
def count_non_distinct_combinations(phf, t):
    k = len(phf[0])
    true_count = 0
    # get all combinations
    for c in combinations([i for i in range(k)], t):
        b = False
        choices = combine_columns_into_array(phf, list(c))
        for row in choices:
            # if the row is completely distinct
            if len(row) == len(set(row)):
                b = True
        # if all rows are non-distinct:
        if not b:
            true_count += 1
    return true_count


phf = [
    [4, 2, 3], 
    [2, 1, 3], 
    [1, 1, 4]]

# first 2 columns have no distinct rows
phf2 = [
    [4, 4, 3], 
    [2, 2, 3], 
    [1, 1, 4]]

print(count_non_distinct_combinations(phf, 2)) # 0
print(count_non_distinct_combinations(phf2, 2)) # 1
```

I plan to use this code as a metric for how "good" the array is - what I mean by this is that I want, given the number of rows `N`, try to reduce this metric as much as possible. Therefore, speed/efficiency is the most important part of any review of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, use iterators. Don't convert to lists constantly:

`get_column` can be simplified to (use generator rather than list):

```
def get_column(phf, c):
    return (x[c] for x in phf)
```

`combine_columns_into_array` to:

```
def combine_columns_into_array(phf, cs):
    return zip(*[get_column(phf, c) for c in cs])
```

In `count_non_distinct_combinations`:

```
for c in combinations(range(k), t):
```

Rather than:

```
for c in combinations([i for i in range(k)], t):
```

To further simplify, `combine_columns_into_array` can be merged with `get_column`:

```
def combine_columns_into_array(phf, cs):
    return zip(*[[x[c] for x in phf] for c in cs])
```

Combining `combine_columns_into_array` into `count_non_distinct_combinations`:

```
def count_non_distinct_combinations(phf, t):
    k = len(phf[0])
    true_count = 0
    # get all combinations
    for c in combinations(range(k), t):
        b = False
        for row in zip(*[[x[i] for x in phf] for i in c]):
            # if the row is completely distinct
            if len(row) == len(set(row)):
                b = True
        # if all rows are non-distinct:
        if not b:
            true_count += 1
    return true_count
```

The `zip(*[[x[i] for x in phf] for i in c])` can be simplified to `([x[i] for i in c] for x in phf)`

The whole

```
k = len(phf[0])
true_count = 0
# get all combinations
for c in combinations([i for i in range(k)], t):
    b = False
    choices = combine_columns_into_array(phf, list(c))
    for row in choices:
        # if the row is completely distinct
        if len(row) == len(set(row)):
            b = True
    # if all rows are non-distinct:
    if not b:
        true_count += 1
return true_count
```

section can be simplified (I think) to:

```
true_count = 0
# get all combinations
for c in combinations(range(len(phf[0])), t):
    s = [[x[i] for i in c] for x in phf]
    # if all rows are non-distinct:
    if not [len(i) for i in s] == [len(set(i)) for i in s]:
        true_count += 1
return true_count
```

And so to:

```
def count_non_distinct_combinations(phf, t):
    true_count = 0
    for c in combinations(range(len(phf[0])), t):
        if not any(len(set(i)) == len(i) for i in ([x[i] for i in c] for x in phf)):
            true_count += 1
    return true_count
```

I admit I lost readability somewhere along the line, but this new 6 line version takes 55.3% of the time needed to complete the `phf2` case, so its almost twice as fast as your version. There may be improvements that can be done to the algorithm, but I'll stop here.